How can I use a conditional type with a generic in a generic function?
I have the following conditional type system for a generic ApiResponse<DataT = void, ExtraT = void> where you can either give it generics or not to produce different results. I wanted to make a generic get function where you could specific the type of the Data in the ApiResponse:
export interface ApiResponseBase {
  Success: boolean;
}

export interface ApiResponseDataAndMaybeCount<DataT> {
  Data: DataT;
  Count?: number;
}

export type ApiResponseMaybeWithData<DataT = void> = DataT extends void ?
  ApiResponseBase
:
  ApiResponseBase & 
  ApiResponseDataAndMaybeCount<DataT>;

export type ApiResponse<DataT = void, ExtraT = void> = ExtraT extends void ? 
  ApiResponseMaybeWithData<DataT>
:
  ApiResponseMaybeWithData<DataT> &
  ExtraT;

// the function I tried to make that produces errors:
export async function getApiResponse<T>(url: string): Promise<T | undefined> {
  const response = await get<ApiResponse<T>>();

  if (response && response.Success && response.Data) {
    return response.Data;
  }

  return;
}

// getter function that returns the generic given, this function is not important it is purely for example purposes
export async function get<T>(): Promise<T | undefined> {
  return {} as T;
}

The idea was to create a type that has Data keys but only when you need them, and extra keys but only when you know what they are and can define them before hand in other types.
Example type outputs:
ApiResponse<> (specify no generics)
produces
  {
    Success: boolean;
  }

ApiResponse<string, {extra: string}> (specify both DataT and ExtraT)
produces
  {
    Success: boolean;
    Data: string;
    extra: string;
  }

The problem is that the type of response is globalThis.ApiResponseMaybeWithData<T> | undefined
and when trying to access response.Data I get the following error:
Property 'Data' does not exist on type 'ApiResponseBase | (ApiResponseBase & ApiResponseDataAndMaybeCount<T>)'.
  Property 'Data' does not exist on type 'ApiResponseBase'.ts(2339)

I know that T is getApiResponse<T>() is required, but there is nothing stopping T from being void so the compiler can't guarantee the outcome of ApiResponseMaybeWithData<T> as one or the other condition.
The type system is based on a backend that I cannot change that sometimes sends Data and sometimes sends all sorts of stuff but always sends Success: boolean at least. I am interested to see how I can adjust this generic getApiResponse<T>() function or adjust the type system to fix the error above. Conditional types seem to be a very useful thing and I have implemented them several places in the project but I am not sure how to get over this hurdle of a generic function accepting a conditional type as the generic.
Edit:
please see this Minimal Reproducible Example:

What's get()?  Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] where we can just copy and paste into our own IDEs and immediately see what you're seeing, without having to reconstruct it first. Generic conditional types are notoriously difficult to implement so it's likely that your issue is just ms/TS#33912 and you'll need a type assertion. But without a [mre] I'm not sure. • Please [edit] to ask a single well-defined question with a narrow scope, as described in [ask]; right now your last paragraph seems to ask multiple less focused questions.

@jcalz I simplified the last paragraph to be more straightforward and added the get() function. I do not know if the get function will be of much use though? I was hoping an answer could be provided with just the type information provided.

@jcalz can you see if the example I added is a valid example?

@jcalz Okay, edited question to have a single code snippet with an MRE and moved around the description to hopefully make it makes sense.

Thanks! So if T is void (which is a weird type, but that's out of scope here), what do you expect Data to be? Maybe you should say it's like {Data?: never} instead of just not mentioned, so TS is happy to index with that key, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

I am setting T's default to be void because I wanted T to be optional and that was a type I had seen others use for an optional generic default as I can then use T extends void to see if the generic was provided or not and T can be anything. Though admittedly that was just a first attempt and I don't know if it makes sense. In the final type I wanted the Data key to not be optional, I wanted it to either exist and be of type T or not exist at all. Sometimes I will need to return the whole ApiResponse<T> type and I didn't want to have to check if Data exists

I do however see that your example works, and I understand why it works. And if I cannot have Data be unmentioned if not defined I can deal with Data being optional and move on.

"not exist at all" isn't a thing in TypeScript. The closest you can get is {Data?: never}.  That means it's either missing, or present but undefined. Isn't that essentially what you mean?  If it's unmentioned it could be anything, not prohibited.  Is there something my version allows that you don't want to support?

Oh I see. Well the backend I am accessing is going to not send Data key at all sometimes so I was trying to make a type system that reflected that. But it sounds like I should just simplify the ApiResponse type and stick with an optional Data which does accurately define the backend's response. So I believe 'just use a regular optional key' is a perfectly valid answer. I was just trying to be sneaky to avoid having to check the existense of the Data key elsewhere in the code.

{Data?: never} does a much better job at communicating "no Data key at all" than {} does. Surely you might decide to simplify to just always make Data optional, but that's not what I'm suggesting here. I'm suggesting to add {Data?: never} where you were previously just not mentioning Data. Does that suggestion serve as an answer to the question as currently asked? If so, I'd be happy to write an answer (and you can, of course, not use that in your actual code base). If not, what am I missing?

oooh I see it now. Then yes that does serve as an answer! And I will take the advice of {Data?: never} since that better describes the situation and is easier to implement.

While it's true that people often run into trouble with conditional types that depend on generics (see microsoft/TypeScript#33912), the issue you're running into isn't very strongly related to that. Instead, it's that you're trying to index into a type with a key (Data) that isn't known on that type.
The conditional type ApiResponseMaybeWithData<T> is a subtype of
ApiResponseBase | (ApiResponseBase & ApiResponseDataAndMaybeCount<T>), and only one of the members of that union type has a Data property. The other, ApiResponseBase, doesn't mention Data at all... and note that this is not the same as saying that a value of type ApiResponseBase lacks a Data property.  TypeScript types are not sealed or "exact" (see microsoft/TypeScript#12936). An object of type ApiResponseBase may well contain a Data property (indeed, ApiResponseBase & ApiResponseDataAndMaybeCount<T> is a subtype of ApiResponseBase).
TypeScript takes the position that it's a mistake to try to index into an object with a key it doesn't know about, because it could be anything at all. If you'd like to say that Data is definitely absent, then you can (mostly) represent that as the type {Data?: never}. Here Data is an optional property of the impossible never type. So either Data is absent, or it's present but its type is never, and there are no values of type never.  So it's definitely absent.  (Well, or undefined, unless you enable --exactOptionalPropertyTypes... or maybe it exists but when you index into the object there's a runtime error, like {get Data(): never { throw "" }}. But these are pathological and not something to worry about.)
So, you could decide to change ApiResponseMaybeWithData to
export type ApiResponseMaybeWithData<DataT = void> = DataT extends void ?
  ApiResponseBase & { Data?: never } :
  ApiResponseBase & ApiResponseDataAndMaybeCount<DataT>;

(and this could be consolidated, moving ApiResponseBase outside the conditional type, but I'll consider this out of scope here).  Now a value of type ApiResponseMaybeWithData<DataT> will always let you access the Data property, and it will either be of type DataT or undefined when you check it:
export async function getApiResponse<T>(url: string): Promise<T | undefined> {
  const response = await get<ApiResponse<T>>();

  if (response && response.Success && response.Data) {
    return response.Data; // NonNullable<T>
  }

  return;
}

And now that works because NonNullable<T> is always assignable to T (where NonNullable<T> is what you get because response.Data is truthy).
Playground link to code
